# SQL window function count top 10 query postgresql redshift

Tags: sql, postgresql, window, amazon-redshift

I'm using SQL, amazon redshift, however it's very similar to PostGres I'm told.

I have a database containing a table with lots of questions in with lots of answers. The questions and answers are duplicated every time someone states that answer. I want a query which lays out unique questions with counts of the answers to those questions. However, I only want to show the top 10 most frequently answered, answers.

So what I did is I did the following. I used a window function to show counts of the answer, partitioned by the question. I sorted the COUNT(answer) descending. However, some questions have lots and lots of different answers that can be given, so the query would lay out hundreds of rows with all the answers in for that question. So I made my window a sub query. I did SELECT * FROM the subquery, and then specified in a WHERE clause outside of the subquery that the window/partition should be less than or equal to 10, to show top ten answers). This worked.

I now want to show the percentage of each answer provided for each question. I can do this with percent_rank or cume_dist window functions. Both have a similar desired effect.

However, I also want to add a column that shows the cumulative percentage. It should show the percentage of how many times the answer was given versus the total amount of answers to that question. As you go down the 10 rows for that question, the percentage should build so that at the tenth row you end at 1.00 or 100%.

The problem is the following: If a question only has 10 or less potential answers, it works perfectly. However, if a question has more than 10 answers, The precent_rank or cume_dist works out the percentage of each answer based on how many total answers there are. I can see that this is not wrong, but I only want to show the top 10 answers as mentioned above and the percentage based on this top 10 only!

Any advice on how to get the query to forget the 100's of other answers and only look at my top 10 I'm showing would be appreciated.

thank you very much
[my query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyxle.png)

`SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT question, answer, COUNT(answer), row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY question ORDER BY count ASC) AS ranker
        ,question as had_to_insert_an_alias, COUNT(answer), cume_dist() OVER (PARTITION BY had_to_insert_an_alias ORDER BY count DESC) AS percent_ranker
    FROM question_table
    WHERE  date_field >= '2013-10-01' and date_field < '2013-10-30' 
    group by question, answer) AS subquery
WHERE ranker <= 10
order by question;`

Comment: It's originally a fork from PostGreSQL 8.0.2, but it's vastly modified underneath.  Also, your question is very lengthy and wordy.  Please include some example data *(Or a link to a SQLFiddle)*, the results that you want and the code that you've tried.  If a picture is worth a thousand word, actual code is worth at least a couple of hundred.

Comment: It would be easier to give you a good answer if you gave your existing query and an example of the table definition.

Comment: hi, i have attached a screenshot showing my query. It is a link at the end of my big question above after i have written 'thank you very much'

Comment: thanks for all help

Comment: p.s. i used row_number() because if i used rank(), if the answer count was 1, it would print these records for as many as there were 1's. So my 'top 10' wouldnt work. If I do row_number it simply returns the top 10 rows.

Comment: @187213 - Please don't post links to screen shots.  I'm not willing to click on potential click-bait from someone with only 1 rep.  Please copy and paste the code in to your question.  There are buttons in the editor to help mark sections as code for specific formatting.  That also helps if we need to copy paste your code for testing or our answers.

Comment: @MatBailie I've added the query in now so you dont have to click the link. thanks

Comment: @Chris-MayhemSoftware any thoughts? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
select question, answer, count, rank, (count::decimal/total::decimal)*100.0 as percent
from (
    select question, answer, count, rank,
        sum(count) over (partition by question order by count) as total
    from (
        select question, answer, count(*) as count,
            rank() over (partition by question order by count desc) as rank
        from question_table
        where  date_field >= '2013-10-01' and date_field < '2013-10-30'
        group by question, answer
    ) q
    where rank <= 10
) t
order by question, rank
```

This is untested so syntax may be off.